# puppet to override bind-address mysql variable

Tags: mysql, puppet

I am using https://github.com/puphpet/puppetlabs-mysql to set up mysql configuration and I need to change bind-address variable to 0.0.0.0.

I am trying to do that as

```
mysql::config::override_options {
    'mysqld' : 'bind-address' => '0.0.0.0'
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Can you help me to advise how this should be done?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind_address instead bind-address

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 18):

The answers don't seem to comply to the latest version of the module (> 3.1).

You can use:

```
    class { '::mysql::server':
      override_options => {
        mysqld => { bind-address => '0.0.0.0'} #Allow remote connections
      },
      # ... other class options
    }
```

Comment: This should be the right answer for the current updated version of puppet.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing it directly to the `mysql` class:

```
class { 'mysql':
    bind_address => '0.0.0.0',
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! my problem was in using dash instead of underscore

Comment: This answer is also now out of date.